# Fourier Transform of Square Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

I wanted to visualise at how the frequency spectrum of square waves changes with duty. But I got stuck at the first hurdle:

```
FourierTransform[SquareWave[x], x, w]
```

Doesn't evaluate. Why not? Can I make it do so?

I tried a couple of other things, like `If[Sin[x]>0,1,0]` but they don't work. I would have thought the built in square wave would have worked.

Answer (score 4):

One way to investigate the spectrum of the `SquareWave` and other periodic functions is via the `FourierSeries`. Here are the first few coefficients:

```
FourierSeries[SquareWave[x], x, 10, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi}]
```

If you want to see real values, then use `FourierSinSeries` and `FourierCosSeries`.

Comment: The Fourier transform of an infinite periodic function is not an easy function to visualize: it's a series of weighted delta functions. The weights themselves are more illuminating, and `FourierSeries` gives you those.

Comment: That's a very useful suggestion.